# Remove http:// or https:// from variable

Tags: php

I am using this code to remove the http:// part of a URL but it doesn't do anything - it just returns the full URL. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php $str = the_field('fl_website');$str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', rtrim($str,'/'));echo $str; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com';
$str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $str);
```

I can see You are doing it similiar way. Maybe the variable is not set as You think it is?

Comment: It works for my data. Maybe Your data is not as You think? show me Your $str variable value.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai = ) That's great.